# Nested commands and help using click

Tags: python, python-click

Consider the example of a nested command using click ([here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/commands/#nested-handling-and-contexts)):

```py
#  foo.py

@click.group()
@click.option("--debug/--no-debug", default=False)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, debug):
    # ensure that ctx.obj exists and is a dict (in case `cli()` is called
    # by means other than the `if` block below)
    ctx.ensure_object(dict)

    ctx.obj["DEBUG"] = debug


@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def sync(ctx):
    click.echo(f"Debug is {'on' if ctx.obj['DEBUG'] else 'off'}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli(obj={})
```

Running `python foo.py --help` returns the follwoing:

```
Usage: foo.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --debug / --no-debug
  --help                Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  sync
```

Note that indication of the "global" option `debug`. However, when running `python foo.py sync --help` the returned string is:

```
Usage: foo.py sync [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

and there's no mentioning of the "global" option. Is there a way to print the options of the parent commands when using click in this way?

Comment: Not super clear what you are after.  Do you want to be able to apply `--global` both before and after `sync`?  Or just want some way to show both the options on the cli and the options on `sync` at the same time?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the latter. When running `foo.py sync`, then implicitly, the global options are impacting the behavior of `sync`. Therefore, it could be helpful that when running `foo.py sync --help` the implicit options will be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why it works this way

In the following call:

```sh
python foo.py sync --help`
```

Click considers the `--help` option to apply to the `sync` subcommand.

If a user wants to see the options to the parent command, they would run:

```
python foo.py --help
```

Click goes even so far to ignore any following arguments after parsing a `--help` (*eager parsing*):

```
python foo.py --help these will be just ignored
```

#### Modifying the --help output

I'm assuming that you would want something like:

```sh
$ clicmd subcmd --help 
Usage: clicmd subcmd [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]   # (as provided by click)

Some usage instructions                         # (as provided by click)

Options:
# options for `subcmd`                          # (as provided by click)

Inherited/global options from `clicmd`:    # (This section would be new)  
# relevant options that apply here 

Commands:
# subcommand info, if any.                 # (as provided by click)
```

To do something like this, you could to extend from the `click.command` class and implement the `format_options` function.
https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.Command.format_options

```py
class YourCmd(click.Command):
    def format_options(self, ctx, formatter):
        # implement your extra options here

@click.command(cls=YourCmd)
def your_cli_cmd():
    pass
```

###### only partly related but maybe useful to you

Let's say you want to access the options of a parent command only once or twice.
For this, you can use `@click.pass_context` to get the parent's command options.

Here is a minimal example I've just written up for you:

```py
@click.group()
@click.option("--debug/--nodebug", help="Toggle for verbose logging output")
@click.pass_context
def how_to_access_parent(ctx, debug):
    ctx.ensure_object(dict)
    ctx.obj["DEBUG"] = debug


@how_to_access_parent.command()
@click.option("--childopt", type=click.INT, help="something childish")
@click.pass_context
def childcmd(ctx, childopt):
    parent_cmd = ctx.parent.command
    for param in parent_cmd.params:
        click.echo(param.get_help_record(ctx))
        # ('--debug / --nodebug', 'Toggle for verbose logging output')


how_to_access_parent(obj={})
```

Comment: The `gh` command is a good example of a CLI that uses 'inherited options' in its documentation. For example https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_diff